# Fetch Tumblr Post ID and use to rename file

Tags: php, api, tumblr

I'm a (very) amateur coder and need help figuring out a problem I would like to implement for my Tumblr.

I have a folder of plain .txt files with each txt filename corresponding to a specific Post ID on my Tumblr.

I want to create something where the most recent Post ID can be automatically fetched once a day and used to replace a file name in an existing folder, so that the chain of events goes:

1. I create file "/files/replace.txt"
2. Code fetches the Post ID from the most recent post on my Tumblr (maybe at a specified time each day?)
3. Code renames "/files/replace.txt" to "/files/{PostID}.txt"

Right now I'm doing this manually, which is becoming almost impossible to keep up with. Any ideas on how to execute this?

Thanks so much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are the text files hosted? Your personal computer? A server somewhere?

This would be very easy to implement. Create a small script in the language of your choice (you've tagged the post as PHP) that makes a call to the [Tumblr API](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2). From there examples, you could retrieve a listing of your latest posts with a call like this:

```
 http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/YOURBLOG/posts/text?api_key=YOURAPIKEY
```

The script could then take the latest Post ID and rename `replace.txt`. Assuming this is running on a linux server, a simple CRON job would set this to run at any interval you wish (5 minutes? 5 hours? once a day?)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The files are hosted on an external server, not my own computer. And I shamefully have no idea how to go about coding it, but this gives me a good start.

Comment: Then setting this up shouldn't take much at all, have a look at the Tumblr API documentation I linked above, and write yourself a small script that just fetches the latest PostID. Once that works, you can make it rename the file with the new PostID, and then your done! Set the script to run with CRON (http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/)

Comment: Nice! Would there be a way to implement this if the files were on my own personal computer? Or would that be more complicated?

Comment: Shouldn't be much different, the same script will work fine you just need to schedule it to run. Assuming your running a Windows machine, CRON won't be available. Have a look at `Windows Scheduled Tasks` (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7)